# 你不敢吃我 What's the meaning of this?

Tags: meaning, idioms

> 你不敢吃我

What's the meaning of this?

Is it something like don't fool me?

Comment: Not enough content to tell. 你不敢吃我 (you do not dare to eat me) could mean different things in different context

Comment: Also notice that "吃" may be used to express sexual suggestion in slang. [<1>](https://www.zhihu.com/question/27601818)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This 吃 means to take.

Example 1: Chess game 西洋棋

> 你吃我的騎士，我就吃你的王后。
>   If you take (attack) my knight, I will take (attack) your queen.

Example 2: Go game 圍棋

> 諒你不敢你吃我那一子，否則我就吃你整片地。
>   I dare you to take (capture) that stone, otherwise I will take (capture) your whole piece of stones.

Example 3: Business competition 商業競爭

> 你應該不敢吃下我的公司，不然我會讓你吃官司，讓你破產。
>   You should not dare to take (occupy) my company, or I will sue you and make you bankrupt.

Example 4: underworld 黑道

> 黑吃黑
>   double cross; stealing from thieves; dog eats dog

Therefore, we can treat 我 in 你不敢吃我 as a pronoun.
It means my stuff, 我的某樣東西.
The real object of this sentence is the stuff, 某樣東西.

Check your context, and you should be able to find the real object, which is not 我 (me).

You dare not take my stuff.

---

Another possibility is to bully, 欺壓 or 欺負.

你不敢吃我。
你不敢欺負我。
I dare you to bully me.